# Understanding putchar loop

Tags: c

This code takes multiple `f`s and prints only 1.  Can someone please explain to me why this code does not print two `f`s?  `putchar` appears twice while not `EOF`.  I have been staring at it for hours and I do not understand how it prints only 1 `f`.
The code is functioning correctly.  I just do not understand how it works step by step.

```
/* A program that takes input of varied 'f's and out puts 1 f */

#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == 'f')
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
        while (c == 'f')
        {
            c = getchar();
        }
        if (c != EOF) putchar(c);
    }   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that when reading characters like this you assume you get `f` but in reality you get `f\n` because you hit the return key after putting in `f`. So the next `getchar()` reads `\n`. So the flow becomes: getchar f, putchar f, c == f so read next char which is \n and then that is printed. Back to outer while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll step through with comments in the code; for `f` (or in reality `f\n`) as input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) // You type f and hit return key (remember this)
    {
        if (c == 'f')  // c contains 'f' is true
        {
            putchar(c); // print 'f'
        }
        while (c == 'f') // c == 'f' is true
        {
            c = getchar(); // '\n' is buffered on stdin from return key
                           // so getchar() returns '\n'. So c will be set to '\n'
                           // It goes back to the while loop and checks if c == 'f'
                           // but it's not, it's '\n'! So this will run once only.
        }
        if (c != EOF) putchar(c); // '\n' != EOF, so print '\n' newline, back to loop
    }   
}
```

Thus giving `f\n` as input will yield the output `f\n`

In the case of input `fffff` (in reality `fffff\n`), see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) // You type fffff and hit return key
    {
        if (c == 'f')  // c contains 'f' is true, first 'f'
        {
            putchar(c); // print 'f'
        }
        while (c == 'f') // First loop, c == 'f'
                         // Second loop, c == 'f'
                         // Last loop, c == '\n', so false
        {
            c = getchar(); // First loop: 'ffff\n' is still buffered on stdin
                           // c = 'f', loop again
                           // Last loop: c = '\n'
        }
        if (c != EOF) putchar(c); // '\n' != EOF, so print '\n' newline, back to loop
    }   
}
```

You see that your inner `while` loop will eat all the `f` until you hit `\n`, thus the same affect as above.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I feel I'm getting closer but I do not understand this line = '\n' is buffered on stdin from return key, c = '\n

Comment: `getchar()` reads one character from standard input. Thus you hit `f` on keyboard and then hit ENTER/RETURN key to "say your done with input". The RETURN key itself is one character, so you have two characters on stdin now but `getchar()` reads out only one. This means that the `\n`, the RETURN key character, is still left buffered. So the next `getchar()` will read just that.

Comment: I'm finding it impossible to get my head around but thank you for trying to help

Comment: How does \n get stored to c if the loop only performs getchar while 'f'?

Comment: @SimonSwallow The while condition is checked first. In the first example `while (c == 'f')` is `true`, so then it does `c = getchar()`. Now getchar will read _one_ character from stdin, and stdin contains `\n` <-- From when you hit RETURN. So `c` does now contain `\n`. The next iteration in the while loop, `c` will NOT be equal to `f`, it's `\n` so we skip the code inside the inner while loop and go down to the last `if`, which is _not_ equal to `EOF` so it prints `\n`. Remember that the code is **sequential**, it reads from up to down.

Comment: @SimonSwallow I updated my first example with some more text.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(c == 'f')
    putchar(c);
```

This prints one `f`, the one you see.

```
while(c == 'f')
    getchar(c);
```

This is where the `f` disappears. If you just used `putchar(c)` before, that means that the loop will execute at least once **because** `c == f`. So the `f` is gone (`c != f`)

Finally, you just use `putchar(c)` on the first character which is not `f`.

Comment: When it loops back around again, why wouldn't it print f again.  So if I were to type ffff I would get f f f f

Comment: @SimonSwallow The while loop will consume all the `f` after a single `f` is read. So if you type ffff, i will print the first f, consume the three left f, and when c =! f, prints `\n`.